# Silverlight Object Loads Then Disappears

Tags: silverlight, dictionary, devexpress

I am using Windows 7 Ult., IE9, Chrome. I have just installed Silverlight 5 and am trying to develop an app using DevExpress DXMap control and Silverlight. However, I am having issues with Silverlight it seems. When I go to this site (http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/what's-new-in-silverlight-5/introduction-to-silverlight-5-3d) to watch a video on the Silverlight 3d feature, the video player which I believe is a Silverlight control loads, but then disappears. When I run the app with the DXMap control, the page loads a blank area with only the zoom control, navigation pad, and scale visible. 
I have tried finding a solution to this problem, but have not been successful. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out what was the issue. I thought that not checking the "Host the silverlight application in a new web site" option (since I never had a website as yet) would let the application load on its own, but I had to enable the "Host the silverlight application in a new web site" option to get it associated with a test page.